# Comparing a bypass attempt to a string javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

From the name of the question this might seem like an easy task, but im a beginner. What I need to do is compare a string (user input, I already have it), with a list of words. Basically if the user inputs bluuexel I still want to have the program to interpret it as blue (im actually making a bot to censor words and just entering random stuff is a common strategy to bypass censors). I was going to sort and delete duplicates but then I realized that "ass" would become "as" and this strategy wouldnt be as applicable.

Comment: You will hardly receive a satisfactory answer to the question because it’s complex and doesn’t belong to JS domain for the most part, also not specific enough. You may want to learn about NLP and normalization first. But why is it supposed to link blue and bluuexel ? They aren’t even remotely similar besides blu part. as and ass are much more similar for both a human and a machine. Try some score based comparison lib like string-similarity, maybe the result will suit you.

Comment: @EstusFlask I did not think about how the poster might be considering NLP processing, but none the less. I figured it had to do with analyzing substrings so, might have been some help or guidance. Great comment on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For analyzing strings, you may use `String.prototype.includes` to see if a substring is located in a string or other options such as Regex for exact matches. Many approaches may be applied, but this example may get you started. [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

For replacing other strings, you something such as `String.prototype.replace`. [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Since you also tagged this post under Node.js, to receive user input from the command prompt. Use may use the Node.js readline module. [Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

Beware of the comparison `item.value == search` may cause unexpected type coercion also. That is why we are using `====`.

> Note

Your question is a little broad, but it seems you are trying to compare strings against other strings. It would help to provide some code so we get a sense of what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
var items = [{
    value: "one"
  },
  {
    value: "bluuexel"
  }
]

// Accept a search string term variable
unique = (search) => {
  // Iterate through the object items
  // Some: Determines whether the specified callback function
  // returns true for any element of an array.
  return items.some(item => {
    // Return if item.value is equal to the search string, beware of 
    // Comparison item.value == search may cause unexpected type 
    // coercion. So we use ===
    return item.value === search
  });
};

// Accept a search string term variable
contains = (search) => {
  // Iterate through the object items
  // Some: Determines whether the specified callback function
  // returns true for any element of an array.
  return items.some(item => {
    // Includes: Returns true if searchString
    // appears as a substring of the result of converting
    // this object to a String, at one or more positions that
    // are greater than or equal to position; otherwise, returns false.
    // Return if item.value contains equal to the search string
    return item.value.includes(search)
  });
};

console.log('Unique:', unique('bluuexel'), '=> bluuexel');
console.log('Contains:', contains('bluu'), '=> bluu');
console.log('Contains:', contains('bluu2'), '=> bluu2');
console.log('Unique:', unique('one'), '=> one');
console.log('Unique:', unique('one2'), '=> one2');
```

Now for removing words from an array or duplicates, also many other approaches. But here is a simple example.

We also make use of the `Spread syntax (...)` allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in short terms. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

The `Set` constructor lets you create Set objects that store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references. [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set)

```js
// Defined list of an array of words
let words = ['bluuexel', 'bluuexel2', 'bluuexel'];
// ... Spread operator to iterate over array elements in array "words"
console.log('Removed (Duplicates)', words);
let removed = [...new Set(words)];
// Output unique only words, from new array named "removed"
console.log('Removed (Non Duplicates)', removed);
```

Putting it together to remove some banned words and also duplicates.

```js
// Filtering words and duplicates

// Word List
let words = [ 'one',
              'one',
              'two',
              'two2',
              'ass',
              'as']

// Banned Words
let banned = ['ass']

// Contains word, accepts a string and a list as an array
contains = (search, list) => {
  // Determine if the list has a string
  return list.some(item => {
    return item.includes(search)
  });
};

// Function for filtering, and removing duplicates and banned words
function filter() {
  // Remove duplicates first, update word list
  words = [...new Set(words)];
  // Iterate through banned word list
  banned.forEach((word) => {
    // Output that banned word was found
    console.log('Found Banned (Word):', word)
    if (contains(word, words)) {
        // Update final word list
        words.splice(words.indexOf(word), 1);
    }
  })
}

console.log('Previous Results', words)
// Run filter function
filter()
// Output results
console.log('Final Results', words)
```